# JAVA Windows Calculator - Inverse Repetition is Constant on the Output

Tags: java, output, calculator, repeat, concatenation

Hi there I am here again, 1st Year Computer Engineering Student from the Philippines, I have an unfinished windows calculator, I just need your help for my assignment. I already have the function of numbers and operations that is needed for my calculator,

**PROBLEM:** for example the number I inputted is **1**

I clicked inverse two times, the output above is only **1/(1)** instead of **1/(1/1))** and so on just like on windows calculator. I think there is an easy way to do this besides using concat.

Please help me also a newbie here thank you. Here is my codes:

```
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            String global = global.concat("1/("+ inputtedNumber + ")");
            textInput.setText(global);
            textOutput.setText(1 / inputtedNumber);
```

**textInput** is for the input like these **1/(1)** while the **textOutput** is for the answer of inverse.

Comment: And by the way, to make it clear. I output I was saying is here in the link prnt.sc/rgyhos . That will happen when you clicked your inverse function multiple times.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean like this? [image of win10 calculator using inverse multiple times.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SQEn7.png)

Comment: Yes like that. How to do that?